How could I make the player rotate towards the cursor in pygame?
import pygame
pygame.init()

SREEN_WIDTH = 1920
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

border = pygame.image.load("border.png").convert_alpha()

cursor_image = pygame.image.load('mouse.png')

text = pygame.image.load("TEXT.png").convert_alpha()

player = pygame.Rect((300, 250, 30, 30))

run = True
while run:/

    cursor_xy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    screen.fill ((0,163,100))

    screen.blit(text, (900,500))

    screen.blit(border, (0,0))

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), player)

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_a] == True:
        player.move_ip(-3,0)
    if key[pygame.K_d] == True:
        player.move_ip(3,0)
    if key[pygame.K_w] == True:
        player.move_ip(0,-3)
    if key[pygame.K_s] == True:
        player.move_ip(0,3)

    screen.blit(cursor_image, cursor_xy)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if key[pygame.K_e] == True:
            run = False
    pygame.display.update()



pygame.quit()


Is your player supposed to be a rectangle? Or are you intending to use an image in future? I ask as they require different approaches (someone's done the heavy lifting here and here). Fundamentally, you have two problems: Working out the angle between the player and the cursor AND rotating the player to that angle. Which are you struggling with?

i am scrapping this but now its going to be a stationary image in the corner pointing at the mouse pointer
